# Context-Free Grammar / Automata

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

$$
L=\left \{ a^n b^m c^z : m \neq z, n \geq 1 \right \}
$$

Can anyone have a look at my answer? Seems correct?
$$
\\S\rightarrow TD|AR
\\R\rightarrow bRc|Y
\\X\rightarrow Xb|b
\\Y\rightarrow Yc|c
\\A\rightarrow Aa| \lambda 
\\T\rightarrow Ta|a
\\D\rightarrow bDc|\lambda 
$$

Comment: But I am sure you have the ability to type the question and your work here in your post. Please make an effort to ask a good question -- that will increase your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I typed the question myself in LaTeX to be clear and posted its image here!

Comment: Well, then this should be really simple for you! Just copy-and-paste that LaTeX code in here. MathSE understands LaTeX!

Comment: Yes, thanks. Edited it.. Just had to insert '$$' before and after the code! thanks

Comment: If you make the substitution $S\to TD$ it seems like you always get $m=z$.  Also, $X$ seem superfluous, and there's no reason to have both $T$ and $A$ that I can see.

Answer (score 1):

Your grammar is more complicated that it needs to be, if I'm not mistaken.  We need something to generate a nonempty string of a's, followed by a string of b's, followed by a string of c's, where the the b and c strings must be of different lengths.

$$S\to AR\\
 A\to a|aA$$

Takes care of the first part.  As for $R$, we want to generate a number of b's followed by the same number of c's, and then stick a nonempty constant string in the middle.

$$R\to bRc|B|C\\
B\to b|bB\\
c|\to c|cC
$$